# html parser stays the same

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on a script that alerts me if something changes on that webpage. I use bs4 and python selenium. Problem is that bs4 never actually gets the new page source.

```
driver.get("some url")
while (True):
  html = driver.page_source
  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
......
  driver.refresh()
```

Any ideas on that? I tried driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")).text instead or entered the page again instead of refreshing it with driver.get(driver.current_url) but those didn't work out for me.

Comment: You're sure you're not doing a `continue` anywhere in the loop that would skip the refresh?

Comment: Pretty sure! I just dont understand it man..

Comment: Perhaps try it with the `driver.get("some url")' within the while loop as well ?

Comment: I already tried that. Didnt work out for me.

Comment: If that doesnt work, and the goal is only to check if the page changes, try my answer below

Comment: I don't know how BeautifulSoup works but perhaps it doesn't wait for the page to fully load? For debugging purposes, have you tried adding a sleep in the first line of the `while` and see if that changes things?

Comment: @JeffC wow, that was the solution. It actually works now! So funny. THANKS!!!!

Comment: @delamain Great. I've added my comment as an answer and added a few details. Please accept it so that the question isn't left unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how `BeautifulSoup` works but perhaps it doesn't wait for the page to fully load? For debugging purposes, I would try adding a sleep in the first line of the while and see if that changes things.

```
driver.get("some url")
while (True):
  time.sleep(5)
  html = driver.page_source
  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
  ......
  driver.refresh()
```

The sleep was for debugging purposes, a better practice is to find an element on the page that you are sure is loaded last and then add a WebDriverWait for that element, e.g. a TABLE or IMAGE, etc.

Comment: Converting my comment into an answer so you can accept it and the question isn't left unanswered.

Comment: An elaboration of said "better practice" can be found on my answer below, if anyone's interested. One other good thing about that method is that it is practically `sleep()` but if it finds the element before the set time, it stops 'sleeping' at that point , unlike time.sleep() which would complete the set time before proceeding

Answer (score 1):

You could try requests module instead for getting the page source

```
import requests


while True:
    res = requests.get("some url")

    #check for error
    try:
        res.raise_for_status()
    except:
        continue

    html = res.text
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    ...
    res.close() # Make sure to do this at the end of the loop
```

**EDIT:** After reading your comment, maybe you should try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait    
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10) # 10 for 10 seconds wait
...
```

Then jus before the part where you search for the element

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input selector here"))) # Replace "input selector here" with the css selector
```

This returns an exception if the element is not found in set amount of time, so you might want to use:

```
try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input selector here")))
except:
    continue # or pass
```

you can change the CSS_SELECTOR to XPATH or CLASS_NAME if you like and likewise replace the "input selector here"

Comment: Hey man, first of all thanks for your help. My program waits for a specific element to occur. I tried it with starting in a page without that element and from that page opened another page (in the same session) which has that element but my program didnt notice that element. When I start that program which has that specific element my program notices it and alerts me, because it is the initial page source..

Comment: If youre waiting for a specific element, have you done that using `WebDriverWait` ?

Comment: It is not always on the page. It is a online shop. If an article gets available, my program is supposed to tell me that. But even if that article gets available, my bot doesnt notice that. And I am pretty sure that the algorithm to alert me is correct because it works when I search for an article which is available on the initial run of the program.

Comment: Could you maybe add more of the code youre using to achieve this? It will surely help us to help you out

Comment: Its edited now. Maybe it adds some clarity.